# Что лучше использовать, JSON, SQL, или что-то другое

Tags: javascript, sql, json

Хочу создать приложение для размещение расписания в учебных заведениях с возможностью добавлять замены, мигалки и тд. Данные, понятно, будут храниться в виде таблицы. Вопрос, в каком формате лучше всего хранить эту таблицу, если у меня особо зависимостей не будет (класс/группа - расписание). Опыте в создании такого по нет, до этого писал только лабораторки в учебное заведение. Хочу сделать что-то полезное и требуется ваша реальная помощь. Стек примерно такой - html,css,js; node.js; с базой данных не решился.

Comment: _"у меня особо зависимостей не будет"_. Это Вам сейчас так кажется. Начнете разбираться, мало не покажется. Некоторые занятия проходят в специализированных кабинетах/аудиторях - если есть всего один кабинет химии, то два занятия по химии в одно время ставить нельзя, придется это учитывать. У предметов есть преподаватели - химик не сможет заменить англичанина, если тот заболел. Кто-то из преподавателей работает на полставки, и доступен только по понедельникам и вторникам. У учебного заведения может быть несколько корпусов, надо учитывать время, чтобы перейти из одного в другой. И так далее...

Comment: способ взаимодействия с бд - graphQL (^^), очень удобно, попробуйте

Answer (score 3):

как я понимаю, это будет клиент-серверное приложение (сервис), включающее:

1. клиентская часть (фронтенд) будет выполнен в виде сайта (html, css, javascript), который вы создадите с помощью какого-нибудь фреймворка React, Angular, Vue
2. серверную часть (бэкэнд) для обработки запросов от клиента и работы с БД или файлами (в которых будут храниться расписания), которую вы создадите на php, c#, python и т.д.
3. данные все таки лучше хранить в базе данных, типа Mysql (бесплатная) или MSSql и обращаться к ней через sql запросы (лучше всего конечно к хранимым процедурам)
4. для графического интерфейса клиентской части вы можете использовать какой-нибудь графический фреймворк типа bootstrap

Итого вам может понадобиться к примеру такой набор:

1. клиентская часть: typescript, react, bootstrap
2. серверная часть: php
3. база данных: mysql

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вы новичок и опыта работы с приложениями мало

я предложу для начала хранить данные в json файлах,
доводы:

1. Связи можно хранить тут же в самих данных.
2. Не нужно жестко структурировать, легко модифицировать.
3. Не нужно изучать/покупать/хостинг баз данных (это отдельная тема и не сказать что там все просто)
4. Данных не много. (много отдельная тема)

Далее по мере разрастания ваших данных вы можете файловый источник заменить на базу данных. И для начала это просто будет No SQL (mongo, redis, ...). B дальнейшем если вдруг у вас приложение потребует бальшой работы с структурированными данными можете перейти на SQL.